# Running a script from a docker image

Tags: linux, bash, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to run the project given [here](https://github.com/matheusdiogenesandrade/latex_docker). It is an algorithm for compiling LaTeX from a docker container. But I am struggling to execute the last command of the given steps. Follows a list of the commands I am typing.

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
su ${USER}
IMAGE=blang/latex:ctanfull
docker pull ${IMAGE}
docker run "$IMAGE" run.sh
```

However, the last command returns the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "run.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container:
```

It seems the docker container is not able to find files in my local directory.
Precisely, I have to call a docker container, and from this container execute a local bash script, without changing the docker image.
I also tried other commands, listed below.

```
docker run --rm --entrypoint '' blang/latex:ctanfull sh -c "./run.sh"
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint '' blang/latex:ctanfull /bin/bash -c "./run.sh"
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint '' blang/latex:ctanfull sh -c "./run.sh"
```

But none of them is capable of finding the `run.sh` script.

Thanks for attention, and best regards.

Comment: Where is the `run.sh` file located? you mentioned that you could run it if you exec to the container, so I assume you know where it's located.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At the directory I am running the command. Here is the link for the script https://github.com/matheusdiogenesandrade/latex_docker/blob/main/run.sh.

Comment: The script you try to run in the container is relative to the container's filesystem not your, it seems to me that you are trying to run local file inside the container, is that a fair assumption?

Comment: The message is _"run.sh": executable file not found in $PATH_, so I would either set the PATH in a suitable way, or provide the absolute path for run.sh explicitly.

Comment: @Nash, thanks for the answer. Actually, I want to run the local run.sh script using the programs installed in the container, and output the results locally.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks. But it seems that I will have to find a way for moving my files to inside the container.

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade then you can either build your own image based on the upstream image, copy your file into the image, and set the `CMD` to run your file see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

or simply mount your current path to the container, like in one of the answers provided below

Answer (score 2):

If the `run.sh` is in your local machine you can run like this in the same folder

```
 docker run -v `pwd`:/tmp -it blang/latex:ctanfull sh /tmp/run.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but actually, I was aiming to run the script using the programs of the container, and output everything locally. But not sure if it is possible. If you take a look at the run.sh (https://github.com/matheusdiogenesandrade/latex_docker/blob/main/run.sh), you can see that the script is reading and exporting files locally. So, or I replicate the folder structure (files with everything) into the container, or I find a way to the container contain my local scope.

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers don't have access to the host file system unless you explicitly grant it to them

To give your container access to the run.sh script you can either map the script into the container using a volume mapping, like this

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/run.sh:/script/run.sh "$IMAGE" /script/run.sh
```

Now the run.sh script is accessible inside the container as `/script/run.sh`.

Or, if you prefer, you can pipe the script into a shell in the container, like this

```
cat run.sh | docker run -i "$IMAGE" /bin/sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, as you can see by the script structure, in- and out-put operations are performed by the script (https://github.com/matheusdiogenesandrade/latex_docker/blob/main/run.sh). What forces me to move the entire folder structure to the container. So, now, at least as far as I can see, I would have to move my files to the container and work inside of it.